# Where can i find the yii version of my yii app?

Tags: php, yii

I recently started to work with yii, where can i find the yii version of my yii app?

Comment: How can i check the version without running app?

Comment: It can be found in yii at the bottom of the requirements page.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use [`getVersion()` of YiiBase](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#getVersion-detail)

```
Yii::getVersion();
```

Answer (score 18):

In Linux, run ./yii in the base directory. In Windows, run `yii.bat`. You will get something like:

```
./yii

This is Yii version 2.0.3.

The following commands are available:
[...]
```

Comment: in which Linux operating system, this will work. I tried it in red hat and it is not working.

Comment: It will work in almost any GNU/Linux distro.  You have to run it from the Yii directory created for the project

Answer (score 12):

grep -A 5 getVersion framework/YiiBase.php

Answer (score 10):

From the framework folder and file "YiiBase.php".
Find the function : getVersion()

Answer (score 7):

Add following line after require_once ($yii); in the index file

```
echo Yii::getVersion();
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can find Yii Version in 
CHANGELOG  - file In   YII Install folder