# How to know which version of yii2 is being used and how to upgrade to the latest version of yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am using a version of yii2 installed a few months back. Now I want it to be upgraded to the latest version.How can I know which version of Yii2 is being used and how to upgrade to the latest version of yii2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In console in site folder run `composer update`. And `composer` will update you Yii2.

If you want to know which version of Yii2 you are using run `Yii::getVersion()`.

Answer (score 16):

Run ./yii command, you will get following output:

```
./yii

This is Yii version 2.0.8.

The following commands are available:
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29271811/1897969

Answer (score 1):

With regard to identifying the current version, there is a function `getVersion()` in `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php`. You can simply open the file and examine the return value to see the version of the codebase you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Yii version 2.0.42, PHP 7.3 particularly while login, I found that the User class extends object class while replacing that my code works fine.

```
namespace app\models;
class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{}
```

**Replace with**

```
namespace app\models;

class User extends \yii\base\BaseObject implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{  }
```

my issue resolve.